# Python: For every time "clear" occurs, I want the text to be associated with a list

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I am trying to associate my testing frame with my log file to figure out which instances pass and which ones fail. 
To explain better, here's an example :
I have a list:

```
data = ['F','P'] # first test pass, second test fail
```

and Here's my log file:

```
USER INPUT :  “clear”                   ------
SYSTEM RESPONSE: “Hello! How are you?”        | Fail
USER INPUT : “Good thank you”                 |
SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Okay"                 ------ 
USER INPUT : “clear”                    ------
SYSTEM RESPONSE: “Hello! How are you?”        |
USER INPUT : “I am good, Thank you!”          | Pass
SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Great!"                     | 
USER INPUT : “Good”                     ------
```

So every instance of "clear" shows a new log, therefor I want for the first "clear" till the next clear occurs to be associated with P, I am using html to build the code and whenever P occurs it will be green in color
and every time F occurs, the code with be red

So far what I have is :

```
            for line in lines :
                for i in cc:
                    if (data[i]== 'P'):
                        n = """<p style="color:green;>""" + line + '</p>'
                    else:
                        n = """<p style="color:red;>""" + line + '</p>'
```

I am really unsure of the structure. 
how to find every time "clear" is occuring and assigning it a specific color until the next instance occurs.
Please feel free to ask me any questions regarding this or to further clarify!
Thanks a ton!

Comment: How committed are you to doing this with HTML? Embedding Python in a web page isn't very simple. If you're only doing it because you want color output, you might have better luck with a desktop GUI, or even a command-line program, assuming your shell can handle colored text. [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) is useful in the latter case.

Comment: I think the OP wants to use Python to process the log file and write out to an HTML page. The Python script is run once and then you can view the output in your browser.

Comment: If so, that's not too hard. I was imagining a more dynamic session, where part of the page is rendered, then the user types "clear" or some other data, and more of the page is rendered... That would be tricky.

Comment: @sundance is right! I have all my code built up in a way to get the logs on my browser. It's honestly just the structure of how to get every instance of "clear" until the next "clear". The html part shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re` for splitting log file according `USER INPUT : "clear"`:

```
log_file = """USER INPUT :  “clear”
SYSTEM RESPONSE: “Hello! How are you?”
USER INPUT : “Good thank you”
SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Okay"
USER INPUT : “clear”
SYSTEM RESPONSE: “Hello! How are you?”
USER INPUT : “I am good, Thank you!”
SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Great!"
USER INPUT : “Good”"""

import re
from pprint import pprint

groups = re.findall(r'USER INPUT.*?clear.*?(?:(?=USER INPUT :\s+\Wclear\W)|(?=\Z))', log_file, flags=re.DOTALL)
data = ['F','P']

style = {'P': '<p style="color:green;>', 'F': '<p style="color:red;>'}

html = ''
for d, g in zip(data, groups):
    for line in g.splitlines():
        html += style[d] + line + '</p>\n'

pprint(html)
```

This prints:

```
('<p style="color:red;>USER INPUT :  “clear”</p>\n'
 '<p style="color:red;>SYSTEM RESPONSE: “Hello! How are you?”</p>\n'
 '<p style="color:red;>USER INPUT : “Good thank you”</p>\n'
 '<p style="color:red;>SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Okay"</p>\n'
 '<p style="color:green;>USER INPUT : “clear”</p>\n'
 '<p style="color:green;>SYSTEM RESPONSE: “Hello! How are you?”</p>\n'
 '<p style="color:green;>USER INPUT : “I am good, Thank you!”</p>\n'
 '<p style="color:green;>SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Great!"</p>\n'
 '<p style="color:green;>USER INPUT : “Good”</p>\n')
```

EDIT:

I made an online example how the [regex works here](https://regex101.com/r/D9YynS/1).

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you. Could you please explain how the re.findall is working if it's okay?

Comment: @girlwhocodes I made an simple example and edited my answer. The regex effectively splits input to groups which begin with `USER INPUT: "clear"`. The exact explanation is on external site.

Answer (score 1):

The quick-and-dirty way would be to read all of the text in at once and split on `USER INPUT :  "clear"`.

```
# skip the first line since it's a clear, but not a separator
text = "\n".join(lines[1:])
split_on = 'USER INPUT :  "clear"                   ------\n'
blocks = text.split(split_on)
html_lines = []
for pf, block in zip(data, blocks):
    html_lines.append("<pre style='color:{};'>{}</pre>".format("green" if pf == "P" else "red", split_on + block))

with open("out.html", "w+") as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(html_lines)
```